# 1px gap showing when hover the div (in IE8)

Tags: jquery, html, css

the image below show the problem:

[image]

work in other browser but for some reason IE8 showing 1 gap when I `hover` in my `div.ImageWrap`

can someone know why IE acting like this.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/6TJKf/)
[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ifoquv/2/edit)

html:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td class="first"><div class="imageWrap"></div></td>
          <td class="first"><div class="imageWrap"></div></td>
          <td class="first"><div class="imageWrap"></div></td>
          <td class="first"><div class="imageWrap"></div></td>
          <td class="first"><div class="imageWrap"></div></td>
          <td class="first"><div class="imageWrap"></div></td>
          <td class="first"><div class="imageWrap"></div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

css:

```
table {
  float:left;
  width:100%
}
table td.first {
  width:14%;
}
table td .imageWrap{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:100px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#000;
}
```

js:

```
$('.imageWrap').hover(function() {
          $('.imageWrap').not($(this)).stop().animate({
              opacity: .3
          }, 500);
      }, function() {
          $('.imageWrap').stop().animate({
              opacity: 1
          });
      }, 250);
```

Comment: Are you able to open your fiddle in ie8? Here is [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifoquv/1/edit#/ifoquv/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
table
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Comment: wow this make the problem solve but know the problem occur in `firefox 20.0.1`